# Pytest django url's tests

Tags: django, pytest

I saw some people writing url's test like this:

```
def test_sample_url():
    path = reverse('url_name', kwargs={'pk': 1})
    assert resolve(path).view_name == 'url_name'
```

As for me this test is not checking anything, because if I place 'url_name' in second line then in third it is obviously going to be equal to it.
Am I wrong or missing something?

Comment: can you explain/describe what exactly are to trying to test?

Comment: I am not trying to test anything but to understand what is the point of the code pasted in my post.